# Conveying "under the radar" in a less colloquial way

Tags: synonyms

I am searching for a word to contrast with *iconic*

I want to characterize views of the city as both iconic and *under the radar*, maybe "non-iconic."

I was thinking about saying that a view of the city was undiscovered, but I think that maybe that overstates what I'm think-- I more mean under-appreciated. Are there any other words that come to mind?

Comment: 'Iconic' can mean 'famously and distinctively representative of its type. Suppose so, which bits (famously and/or distinctively and/or representative) would you like to see contrasted (or negated)?

Comment: What do you mean by *view* or *views of the city*? Opinions about the city?

Comment: Are you talking about pictures taken in “little-known” or “out-of-the-way” places?  Maybe they are *candid* shots.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to describe photos of a city that include both subjects and vantage points that are iconic and well know and those that are less so.  I think a bunch of the suggestions help me get at that - "off the beaten path," and "overlooked" I think get me closest to what I'm trying to describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about *best-kept secret*?

The Free Dictionary:

> [*best-kept secret*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/secret): A certain aspect, fact, location, or
>   activity, usually touristic or commercial in nature, that is or
>   purports to be not well known to the public but deserving of praise or
>   attention. (1) *The newspaper called the restaurant the city's best-kept secret. (2) While everyone wants to visit the Ring of Kerry, the Dingle Peninsula is really one of Ireland's best-kept secrets.*

One could also use *well-kept secret*. Thanks to @ktm5124 for the suggestion. I've heard both *best-kept secret* and *well-kept secret*. They both speak to your "under the radar".

**Edit**: Another possibility is *off the beaten track (or path}*.

The Free Dictionary:

> [*off the beaten track (or
>   path)*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+beaten+path): not
>   known or popular with many people; away from the frequently traveled
>   routes. *We found a nice little Italian restaurant off the beaten
>   track.*

Comment: Great answer. Also useful to add "well-kept secret" as an alternative, if you don't want to sound too superlative.

Comment: @ktm5124 Thanks. I thought about adding that. Based on your comment, I will.

Answer (score 1):

***Mundane***, perhaps - ordinary, commonplace, prosaic, dull, humdrum, lacking interest or excitement.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that a certain view of the city is a **hidden gem**. I'm actually having  a hard time finding a definition of this phrase, but it's the same thing as a well-kept secret.

Travelers are often interested in the hidden gems of a city. (Restaurants, views, rooftops, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

How about **overlook**:

According to Cambridge dictionaries online, as a verb, it has the following meaning:

> Overlook – verb, transitive: to fail to notice or consider something or someone.

Answer (score 0):

***less obvious***

I think by "under the radar," you do not mean what [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/under_the_radar) says:

> under the radar: Without attracting notice; in an undetected or secretive manner

I think you mean, rather, simply *undetected*.

If so, *less obvious* or *less well-known* should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd favor ***obscure*** as an antonym of 'iconic' - on the basis that it is used as a metaphor for people who are not well-recognized. I think that the same metaphor could work for parts of a city that are similarly not well-recognized.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the contrast could be made by mentioning those who see the city from that other perspective:
Those in the know...

> If you are **in the know** about something, especially something that
>   is not known about or understood by many people, you have information
>   about it. **[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-know)**

The indigenous view ...

> **indigenous:** originating or occurring naturally in a particular place; native. **[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indigenous)**

The grassroots opinion is...

> **grass_roots:** ordinary people regarded as the main body of an organization's membership. **[Oxford Dictionaries.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grass_roots)**

The most sophisticated expression, the one that those 'in the know' would use, would be

> "The *cognoscenti* say that.."
>   **cognoscenti:** meaning, definition, what is cognoscenti: a group of people who have a great knowledge and understanding of a particular
>   subject…  **[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cognoscenti)**